# Trigger Insert in MongoDB Collection when New Row is Inserted in MySQL DB table

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

Is it possible to trigger an insert into a MongoDB collection when a row is inserted in MySQL, via MySQL Event Handling?

I have a project that makes use of MySQL as the main database, and I'm planning to make use of MongoDB as a cache because I'm using Meteor to make use of Reactiveness of Meteor JS.

Comment: A mysql Trigger or Event call to a UDF ? See [this](http://www.mysqludf.org/)

Comment: @Drew What I mean is If an Insert Event is Triggered in MySQL an insert Event also will be triggered in MongoDB.

Comment: When you say triggered, you mean an actual mysql trigger is being executed. Right? If so, have that call a udf. I wouldn't do it that way due to the setup. I would have some agent polling for a dirty flag if minor latency is acceptable. Say, every few minutes or more often. It then syncs (but that is how I handle it with java and c# anyway. Cuz we knew over time that we needed more powerful programming). The amount of network traffic is minimal. If one were to look at the deluge of traffic that actually occurs, you would find that a call such as get max() to a table of the AI value or tstamp

Comment: .... is pretty minor to say the least in the face of everything else that is going on

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the readability a little, by tidying up sentence structure and word choice. On this site, every user is encouraged to [edit] and re-edit their questions to make them as useful as possible.